# If one deletes a project from Google Developer Console, will it be removed from Google Play Developer Console as well?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-developer-tools

Please read carefully to avoid ambiguity in the use of Google terminology.

I linked my Google Play Games Game to my Google Play Game, and then I had to remove this link in the Google Developer Console. I recreated the link and my SHA1 code became available again. Now I received a message that my previous project will be completely removed from Google Developer Console. Will it also be removed from Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK both serves different purposes, google play is used for launching apps, where as developer console is for using various API's provided by the google.

So **Once you delete your project from developer console it will be gone from google developer console not google play console.** and but you can **restore it until 7 days of deletion**.

Google play console is used for publishing, updating or deleting your Android Apk from Google PlayStore.

Comment: `Once you delete your project from developer console it will be gone.` from the Developer Console? Or from the Play Store? Sorry for asking, I just need to be really sure about this.